# how can I show loading gif until deleting?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gif

I have a delete button on a `repeater` which is in `update panel`. When i click the `delete button`, it can delete, but It takes about 10 seconds. So I want to add a loading `gif` . I am beginner on adding `gif`. Please help me. Thanks for interests

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString='<%$ ConnectionStrings:NET2ConnectionString %>' SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [ProductsRA]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
                <asp:Repeater ID="rptuser" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" OnItemCommand="rpr1_ItemCommand" OnItemDataBound="rpr1_ItemDataBound">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="GridItems">
                                <asp:ImageButton runat="server" ID="delbtn" ImageUrl="~/images/delete.gif" CommandName="Delete" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ID") %>' ValidationGroup="ab" ToolTip="Delete User" /></td>
                            <td class="GridItems"><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"ID") %></td>
                            <td class="GridItems"><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"ProductName") %></td>
                            <td class="GridItems"><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Quantity") %></td>
                            <td class="GridItems"><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"UnitPrice") %></td>
                            <td class="GridItems">
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <FooterTemplate>
                        </table>
                    </FooterTemplate>
                </asp:Repeater>
            </ContentTemplate>
            <Triggers>
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="rptuser" />
            </Triggers>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

this is cs:

```
 protected void rpr1_ItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
{
    DataSet.ProductsRADataTable dt = new DataSet.ProductsRADataTable();
    DataSetTableAdapters.ProductsRATableAdapter adp = new DataSetTableAdapters.ProductsRATableAdapter();

    if (e.CommandName == "Delete")
    {
       adp.DeleteQuery(Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument));
    }
}
```

Comment: please provide code examples for what you have tried

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [UpdateProgess control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386421(v=vs.140).aspx) for this.

```
<asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress1" runat="server"
        AssociatedUpdatePanelID="UpdatePanel1">
    <ProgressTemplate>
        <div class="loading_div">            
            <p>Please wait while we process the request.</p>
            <img src="/Images/loader.gif" />
        </div>
    </ProgressTemplate>
</asp:UpdateProgress>
```

Use an overlay div if you want to block the page while processing the request.

```
.loading_div {
    position: absolute;
    color:#fff;
    background-color: #000;
    z-index: 2000 !important;
    opacity: 0.6;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    padding-top:20%;
}
```

It will render like this while the request is processed: http://jsfiddle.net/codeandcloud/jLmbmLmn/